# hadoop 3.3.1 fs -mkdir No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop3

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hadoop/hadoop_input
mkdir: `hdfs://localhost:9000/home/hadoop': No such file or directory
```

even I create /home/hadoop/hadoop_input folder,the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

OK,I know why.by default,only '/' directory exists.So I have to first create /home,then /home/hadoop, and last create /home/hadoop/hadoop_input.